# Numpy shape gives wrong dimension

Tags: arrays, numpy, matrix

```
print W.shape
```

outputs (7,12288) as it supposed to do. However,

```
print W[0].shape
```

outputs 12288, when it should be 7. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Probably not knowing what's `w[0]` doing?

Comment: Are you mixing up `W[0].shape` and `W.shape[0]`?

Answer (score 0):

W.shape gives shape(size) of object W

W[0].shape gives first element in W's shape

ex :

```
W = np.array([[1, 2], [3, 4], [5,6]])
W.shape
#Out[39]: (3, 2)
W[0].shape
#Out[40]: (2,)
```

You might wanna look at [documentation](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.shape.html)

Answer (score 0):

`W.shape` is multi-dimensional. It has 2 dimensions. It is an array of rank 2.

eg:

```
W=np.array([ [1, 2, 3],
             [4, 5, 6],
             [7, 8, 9],
             [10,11,12] ])
W.shape
```

is

```
(4, 3)
```

Whereas `W[0]` has only one dimension and is hence an array of rank 1.

```
W[0].shape
```

is

```
(3, )
```

See [this](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-dev/user/quickstart.html) post.

One difference between rank 1 and rank 2 arrays is that the transpose of a rank 1 array is same as the array itself.

eg:

```
print(W[0])
```

and

```
print(W[0].T)
```

are both same

```
[1 2 3]
```